# Facebook canvas app details page not accepting my resized image for the banner

Tags: facebook, image-resizing, facebook-canvas, submission

I've used a resizing program to resize my image to the requisite 100 by 155 pixel dimensions for the banner image; but when I upload it I get an error message saying there's something wrong with the dimensions. The image I'm uploading is a stock photo I've purchased and have full rights to, meaning it's not home made. Any idea what else the problem could be. The program im using is pretty old and standard. Is there a specific one that can be recommended that is straightforward and won't give me an error on the facebook details page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for misunderstanding,

Check out these instructions here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/#uploading

Especially those:

- Don't put logos and text against the border of images.
- Make sure banner images fill out the frame completely (and that they leave no white space, no rounded edges or no borders).
- Round the edges of icons. We recommend that you use transparency and PNG, not GIF.

If your problem persist, Try another program. Personally, I use Adobe photoshop (Actions) to generate all graphics for my facebook apps, also there's tons of other programs that can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean facebook cover Photo by banner image then the optimal size for it is 851px by 315px.

Here you'll find a quick Reference for Facebook Timeline Image Sizes:
http://laurenproctor32.com/tag/facebook-image-size/

Have a nice day.

Comment: no i'm submitting an app for review. If you have an app Ferouk and you go to app details, you'll see a section where they specify dimensions for your icon and your banner image. Facebook wont accept mine even though its resized

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, Check my second answer